# How Do i Print last 10 days using php?

Tags: php, days

I want to Print last 10 days from the current day. I want to do this by using php. Please can any one help me.

Answer (score 1):

The questions is of really low quality, but knowing how few people know this, I'll answer it anyway ...

Use the [DateTime classes](https://secure.php.net/datetime):

```
// Current timestamp
$today    = new DateTime();

// For a precise 10 day difference, clone $today
// and substract 10 days from it.
$backdate = clone $today;
$backdate->sub(new DateInterval('P10D'));

// Declare a DatePeriod between the two dates,
// with a 1-day interval in between them
$period = new DatePeriod($backdate, new DateInterval('P1D'), $today);
// Profit
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d'), "\n";
}
```

*It is important to use `DatePeriod` with a start and end date*, as opposed to just telling it do use 10 occurances.
The latter would result in 10 dates *in addition to the starting one*; in other words - you'd get 11 instead of 10 dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($days = 9; $days >= 0; $days--){ print_r( date('d-m-Y',strtotime(date('d-m-Y').' -'.$days.' days'))." "); }
```

Current date format is in 'd-m-Y'. You may change this to your taste. I'm not sure if you'd like today included. If not so, change 9 into 10 and 0 to 1 in the 'for'-construct and it will give you the 10 days before today (excluding today)...